# Stream makes function run forever

Tags: c++, streaming, infinite-loop, infinite

What kind of stream can cause to function run forever ?

Is such stream exist ?

Comment: This question lacks any kind of detail at all.  It can't be answered in its current form.

Comment: Sounds like an interview question to me.

Comment: Why do you need a stream for that? Put `for(;;);` in the end of your function, this make it run forever.

Answer (score 3):

The standard input.

Answer (score 2):

ifstream("/dev/random")
ifstream("/dev/zero")

Answer (score 2):

If a stream encounters an error, it will stop returning/accepting information. If your function is waiting for something to come out of the stream, it will spin forever.

Use `if ( cin )` (cast the stream to `bool`) to test for an error condition. Alternately, call `cin.exceptions( ios::badbit )` at program or stream initialization so an error condition throws an exception rather than quietly spinning.

Call `cin.clear()` (or whatever stream) followed by `cin.ignore()` such as to remove the offending input, if the program is able to recover from such an error.

Comment: Nope, nope... that answer's way too serious. And the question was "what kind of stream", not what stream state. +1 from me anyway ;-)